# Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block file location magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3

How can i find where this function is written  `<?=  $block->getText() ?>`
what does it mean `/* $block \Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block */` Is this file location or what.?

```
/* @var $block \Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block */

?>

 <div class="widget block block-static-block">  
  <?=  $block->getText() ?> 

  </div>*emphasized text*
```

Answer (score 0):

Open

> vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Widget/Block.php

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    parent::_beforeToHtml();
    $blockId = $this->getData('block_id');
    $blockHash = get_class($this) . $blockId;

    if (isset(self::$_widgetUsageMap[$blockHash])) {
        return $this;
    }
    self::$_widgetUsageMap[$blockHash] = true;

    $block = $this->getBlock();

    if ($block && $block->isActive()) {
        try {
            $storeId = $this->getData('store_id') ?? $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $this->setText(
                $this->_filterProvider->getBlockFilter()->setStoreId($storeId)->filter($block->getContent())
            );
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        }
    }
    unset(self::$_widgetUsageMap[$blockHash]);
    return $this;
}
```

Check this method where set text value:

```
$this->setText(
```

this line.